# Colocar consulta de los detalles de un producto que esta en otra tabla dentro de un while

Tags: php, mysqli

Estaba intentando colocar una consulta dentro del `while` para obtener la información de los productos que se encuentran en otra tabla y decidí colocar un `array` rápido pero está no se ejecuta y no muestra la información ¿Algún problema o consejo?

```
    <table class="cart-table responsive-table">

        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Nombre del Producto</th>
            <th>Precio</th>
            <th> Estado del stock</th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        <?php
                //INICIAMOS CON LA BUSQUEDA DE PRODUCTOS DESEADOS DEL USUARIO
                $mysqli->real_query("SELECT * FROM cms_wishlist WHERE User_Id = ".$_SESSION['Id']." ORDER BY Id");
                $resultado = $mysqli->use_result();
                while ($DataProducts = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){

                //INICIAMOS CON LA BUSQUEDA DE LA INFORMACIÓN DEL PRODUCTO
                $result_sql_data_site_d = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM cms_products WHERE Id = ".$DataProducts['Product_Id']." LIMIT 1");
                **$DataProduct = $result_sql_data_site_d->fetch_array(); // de aqui no pasa**


        ?>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="<?php echo $DataProduct['Product_img']; ?>" alt=""/></td>
            <td class="cart-title"><a href="#"><?php echo $DataProduct['Product_name']; ?></a></td>
            <td><?php echo $DataProduct['Product_price']; ?></td>
            <td>
            <?php  if($DataProduct['Product_Stock'] > 0){echo "Disponible";}else{echo "Agotado";} ?>
            </td>
            <td><a href="#" class="button color">Añadir a carrito</a></td>
            <td><a href="delete.php?id=<?php echo $DataProducts['Id']; ?>" class="cart-remove"></a></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </table>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Donde decis de aqui no pasa, que error recibis?

Comment: Nunca es bueno lanzar consultas dentro de la lectura de datos de otras consultas ... mucho menos dentro de un bucle. Me pregunto: ¿si las tablas tienen datos relacionados, por qué no los traes en una sola consulta uniendo ambas tablas mediante `JOIN`? Si las tablas no se relacionan (lo cual sería poco probable), entonces lo correcto es que obtengas los dos conjuntos de datos aparte, en variables y luego los unas.